# 1px pencil draws 3px in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel, pen-tool, pixel-art

I am trying to draw with 1px pencil but it draws 3px square. I checked my grid settings and Im sure that every grid is 1 px. How can I fix that?
[image: 1px pencil draws 3px]

as you see this is 3x3px canvas and pencil is 1px but it fills all canvas.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have a default square or round brush selected. Some brushes don't scale down to 1 pixel.

Comment: Note: Even if you have a square brush selected, if it isn't the 1 pixel brush, it may not actually scale down to 1 pixel in the slider.

Comment: @13ruce thank you I was scaling down to 1px using slider. After I choose from given preset sizes of brush, it scaled down to 1 px.

Comment: Good to hear it worked out. I've added my comment as an answer so you can mark this one answered. Cheers!

Comment: i was having the same problem with pixel art studies. did you solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to select the 1-pixel brush from the square brush set. If you select a larger square brush, the slider may not scale it down to 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the "Pencil Icon" and choose "Reset Tool". Then choose “Brush Tip” of the pencil. Use standard round or square to get one pixel.

Comment: this is the way

Comment: I'm sorry, but after 8 hours of searching, I didn't find anything you mentioned. I see at least 6 "Pencil Icons" in Photoshop window.